# is there some algorithm for save a finest route gps android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location

When we save coordinates gps in android , We know the gps is not precise
for example , Here the blue point is the real coordinates, the red points is the gps gets in several attempts

[image]

this is (not a real ) route, after we drawn the lines if you have (driven/walking/moved)

[image]

this is (other fake ) route which is much more fine, 
is there some algorithm/code for get this result ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you said - you will get different readings even if the GPS is static, due to GPS errors, but that's not the whole story: When you move relatively slow, you're also getting those erros. There are few things you can do about it:

1. Filter out "bad" readings - when you get a location from the GPS, you also get the location's accuracy. Decide a threshold, say 20m and ignore any readings with worse accuracy.
2. Filter out close readings - If the distance between the current location and the previous location is smaller than some threshold (I'd suggest 10 - 20m) - ignore the current location and wait for the next one.
3. You can also use your device's sensors (like the accelerometer) to decide if your device is moving or not. You can see a [code example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640147/googlefit-sensors-api-distance-error/37644468#37644468).